# Binding in Prepared Statement is not working with Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver sqljdbc4.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I ran the following program with sqljdbc4.jar in the classpath. There is data in the  EMPLOYEE table for the employee name DEMO but the following program is not retrieving data for DEMO. When the same program was run with Merlia.jar in the classpath, it was retrieving data for DEMO.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");      
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER23:5000;databaseName=TESTDB", "SYSADM", "SYSADM");

String sqlSele = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNAME like ?" ;
PreparedStatement sts = con.prepareStatement(sqlSele);
sts.setString(1, "DEMO" );      
ResultSet rs = sts.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
System.out.println("driverConn.main()" + rs.toString());
}

}
catch(Exception e)
        {
System.out.println(e);
e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Modified the sql statement as **"SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNAME like ‘DEMO’”(No setString method is used here)** and executed the program again, this time I got the results.

Can someone help me out from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may want to access a column in the result set, not whatever `toString()` will give you: use `rs.getString(1)` to get to the first result set column value (assuming that is a String).

Hint: do not use asterisks in queries. It's more stable to use concrete column names. Otherwise, changes to your database may return the columns in different order, and your code breaks.

Comment: Have you ever faced these types of issues when using sqljdbc4.jar?? The same program is working fine with Merlia.jar.

Comment: I have used the rs.getString(1) in the system.out.print statement but even then there is no output observed on the console.

Comment: The problem may be with the setString() method because when I used SQL statement as "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNAME like ‘DEMO’” (without using setString for binding) I got the output on the console.

Answer (score 0):

What is the column type of 'EMPNAME'? Is it varchar or something like that?
Use the setXXX() method akin to the column type. So if the column type IS of type String or Text, then setString() should work.
If it is of type varchar or nvarchar, etc. you can also use the

```
sts.setObject(1, 'DEMO', java.sql.Types.${AppropriateTypeHere});
```

command. Just confirm the SQLType is available according to the Java version you're compiling with. java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR is not available pre Java 1.6.
Also, is it perhaps required that your parameter placeholder (the ?) needs to be in single quotes? Ie.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNAME like '?'" ;
```

The latter may be incorrect. I encountered it in my struggle with obtaining a estimated query plan using PreparedStatement. So it may not apply to your problem here.